# Can I set thread priority in dotnet? (specifically interacting with Suave webserver, but it's a general question)

Tags: .net-core, f#, suave

I have a tool that does a lot of calculations in a loop. It is creating async tasks and then run them in parallel. About 20% of the time, the CPU is maxed out.

At the same time, I have a REST api, implemented with Suave, used to query the data.
The issue is that when the CPU is busy, Suave will just not reply at all.

Right now, I have about 10 seconds of every minute where the rest calls will not be processed, while the calculations are done, and afterwards requests are processed normally.

So I am trying to investigate if priorities in thread may be the solution for that.

I'm starting Suave like this:

```
let listening, server = startWebServerAsync configuration webApplication
server    |> Async.Start
listening |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

but I was wondering if there is a way to set the priority of the server so that its code is executed if there is a request.

Alternatively, I start all the calculations like this:

```
snapshots
|> List.map (fun snapshot ->
    async {
        return dosomestuff...
    })
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

is there a way to lower the priority of this execution to give a chance for the web server to reply?

or, should I insert some Thread.Sleep(1) in the computation to give a chance to the context switch?

---

What I have tried:

- I've tried to sprinkle the calculations with Thread.Sleep(0) and also Thread.Sleep(1) to see if it helps to do a context switch when there is a Suave request. No effect.
- I've started the calculations in their own thread and set a low priority, like this:

  ```
    let thread = Thread(ThreadStart(processLoop))
    thread.Priority <- ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
    thread.Start()
  ```

  but this didn't change anything either.

---

More detail about Suave:

this is an example of an endpoint from Suave.

```
// get the correlation matrix
let private getCorrelationMatrix () =
    match ReportStore.getReport() with
    | Ok report ->
        {|
            StartTime            = report.StartTime
            EndTime              = report.EndTime
            Interval             = report.Interval
            PublicationTime      = report.PublicationTime
            CorrelationMatrix    = report.CorrelationMatrix
        |}
        |> Json.serialize |> Successful.OK >=> setMimeType "application/json"
    | Result.Error e ->
        ServerErrors.INTERNAL_ERROR e
```

with ReportStore.getReport() just getting the last data, or error, from a mutable.

The Suave endpoint are very lightweight, they just grab the last data, or the last error, from an array and return it.

It really looks like when all cores are busy with parallel execution, no other threads can preempt that. 10s is very long when you wait for a reply!

Comment: Don't ever mess around with primitive thread priority functionality, unless you really know what you're doing. This is not the right way to solve performance issues.

Comment: more than a performance issue, it's a priority issue: I'll keep the CPU very busy at times, on all cores, but I need another thread to always be able to preempt that work; right now when I keep all cores busy 20s in a row, the web server will take 10-15 seconds to acknowledge a request. An alternative is to do the parallel work on all cores but one, but I'm not sure how that'll work on AWS in a docker container

Comment: You're calling Async.RunSynchronously in a Suave handler? That might be tying up a socket while the calculations are going on. Async.Parallel + Async.RunSynchronously is great when you can tie up the UI thread (with a waiting indicator), as the user has to wait until these are finished. You might need to do things differently on a web server.

Comment: @JimFoye, no I'm not calling it in the handler: I've a loop that waits for data, does computations and stores the last result of those. At the same time, I've a simple rest api that always returns the last result from the storage space, so the two are totally unconnected. But while the computations are going on, the webserver doesn't reply in a reasonable timeframe

Comment: Ok. How is access to the storage done? The Suave thread is not blocked even while a new calculation is happening?

Comment: @JimFoye, the storage is a mutable variable holding a type with a bunch of arrays. Based on the request, I return one of the arrays. I edited the question by adding the code of one of the endpoints to give an idea. The code in Suave is unremarkable, there is nothing time / memory consuming in it.

Comment: Are you serializing thread access to the mutable variable? Seems like you might need to be concerned with consistency there. (I realize this may have nothing to do with your problem but I feel like I have to ask).

Comment: @JimFoye, no, I don't: it's updated once at the end of all the calculations and any rest query will get whatever version is the last written, it's something that doesn't really need to be exact since it's data always in flux and it's just used for general trends